# ng-selected does not work but modifies option as selected="selected", working with ng-repeat

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I need the value that is obtained from my db is selected. Inspect in html, I see that the value of one of the `<option>` changes to: `selected="selected"` but in the select it is not really selected.

Here is my code:

```
<select chosen class="form-control" name="state" ng-model="product.state" ng-change="updateData()" placeholder-text-single="'Select one'" required >
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option ng-repeat='i in statesList' value="{{i.id}}" ng-selected="i.id == product.state.id">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I tried to change the value of `ng-model` by `ng-model="product.state.id"` and it works, it stays selected, but of course, the data is not saved later.

`statesList` is the array of objects that are retrieved from a mongodb database collection.

I have read other similar questions but I can not solve my problem with them. I am new at angular and there are complicated problems for me. What solution is there? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

No need to have ng-change handler.
Try below approach by using ng-options. The model will always have latest selected value.

```
<select name="state" id="state"
  ng-options="option.name for option in statesList track by option.id"
  ng-model="product.state"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project i have handled selects control with Reactive form, you can try like this

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      "testselectControl": []});
```

in html

```
  <select id="test1" formControlName="testselectControl"
        class="form-control p-0 start-date-input-box ">
        <option *ngFor="let val of listValues" [value]="val.id">
          {{name.name}}</option>
      </select>
```

when you receive data set value like this

```
 this.testForm .get("testselectControl").setValue(listValues ? (listValues.find((value) => (value.id.trim() ==selectedValueId) : "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select multiple ui-select2="{allowClear: true}" ng- 
 model="selectedCountries" data-placeholder="Countries">
 <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.id}}"> 
 {{country.name}}</option>
 </select>
 <button ng-click="fetch()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Apply</button>
```

the solution of adding priority worked